# Angularjs RangeSlider and Checkbox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, slidetoggle, rangeslider

I found this example on Google.

Is there a way to start with following properties:

```
  $scope.slider_all_options = {
minValue: 0,
maxValue: 100,
options: {
  floor: 1,
  ceil: 100,
  step: 1,
  precision: 0,
}
```

};

Then change the minValue to 1 for the RangeSlider if the checkbox is checked and back to 0 when the Checkbox is unchecked? I cannot solve this problem at the moment.

Please take a look at my JSFiddle:

[Here is my JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3gzfk6q/1/)

Comment: Hello, I don't know if I understood your problem... I did this, you can check if this can solve your problem: https://jsfiddle.net/w3gzfk6q/2/

Comment: Thank you. thats what i need.

Comment: You are welcome. I'll post an answer, because this can help other people.

Answer (score 0):

I did this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3gzfk6q/2/), I think it is what do you need.

Just add the model to you checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="toggleHighValue()" ng-model="check">
```

And implement the toggle function like this:

```
  $scope.toggleHighValue = function() {
  if ($scope.check) {
      $scope.slider_all_options.minValue = 1
    } else {
      $scope.slider_all_options.minValue = 0
    }
  }
```